# modulus of $\sin(z)$ where $z$ is a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm asked to show if there exists $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that, the two following conditions are simultaneously satisfied

$$|\sin(z)|>1,  |\cos(z)|>1$$

For $|\sin(z)|^2$  I find $\displaystyle\frac{1-\cos(2z)}{2}$ wich is not a real number in general because $\cos(z)$ is not a real number. I don't know where is the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that

$$\sin(z)^2 = \frac{1-\cos(2z)}{2}$$

but then you have to take the absolute value also on the right side. So:

$$|\sin(z)^2| = \left|\frac{1-\cos(2z)}{2}\right|$$

As for your exercise, write

$$\sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}, \cos(z) = \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$

and try finding a value for $z$ such that the absolute value of both expressions is $>1$. Putting in purely imaginary numbers helps.

Comment: I mean modulus squared wich is $z\cdot z^*$ and the exercise that you propose is the actual exercise I'm trying to do. Moreover, i derived the expression in my question from the definitions of $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ I don't get the purely imaginary numbers part, because $e^{iz}=e^{i(x+iy)}=e^{ix-y}$ both real and imaginary part.

Comment: So actually you're looking for $|\sin(z)|^2>1$ and $|\cos(z)|^2>1$? That does not make a difference, since $|z|>1$ if and only if $|z|^2>1$. Anyway, you can swap $|.|$ and $z^2$: $|z^2|=|z|^2$. Regarding the purely imaginary numbers, try setting $z=iy$ with $x=0$ and calculating $e^{iz}$ with that.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be enough just to pick an $x$ such that $e^{ix}$ is pretty big? Then since you have $\sin x\approx {\frac1{2i}e^{ix}}$ and $\cos x\approx \frac12 e^{ix}$ you would have what you wanted.

---

So for example, taking $x=-1000000000i$ ought to suffice.

Comment: Hi, yes but I'm looking for an analytical expression, if possibl :)

Comment: @burzum You said you were asked to show *if* there exists such a $z$. So it should be enough to produce one such $z$.  What do you need exactly?

Comment: You're right indeed, my bad. I'm asked to determine a number $z$ such that the two conditions are satisfied.